# Accessing all layers displayed on map in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to access names of all layers that I display on the map using Mapbox GL with React.

Is there any specific method that enables me to access that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42984268/5602923

Comment: First, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I did this code map.getStyle().layers --> and it returns all layers with their styles only without data. What I want is filter all layers that I added on map to polygons layers only. If you know something may help me on that, please send me it